# Is there any detailed list of all website elements?

Tags: website-design, lists

I'm trying to build a database with all the elements of a website to catalogue and organize the best practices, from a UX point of view, for each of them. Is there any online resources to start from?

For an e-commerce website, for example, there's a Product Page composed by: title, main picture, gallery, description, detailed informations, price, quantity, add to cart button...

Answer (score 1):

Not in the way you mention because, I think.

Because a 'main picture' isn't very descriptive. It would likely be classified as a header and a picture, for example. And price and quantity aren't website elements, they're probably just text(boxes). And an add-to-cart-button is just a button.

If you're talking about elements you should separate the element and the function. Because an image can be many things; header, background, advertisement, illustration or screenshot to explain something, etcetera. Similar to how a plank can be either a table, a bench or even a wall.

But you can take a look at sites like:

- [usability.gov](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/user-interface-elements.html)
- [semantic ui framework](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html)
- [Windows developer docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373675(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls.html)
- [IOS developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/interface-essentials/)

and get a some idea of the basic elements. You'll note that some organizations do actually differentiate subcategories like menu-button and share-button, but those categorizations are far from universal.